# MYSQL: subquery return as table name in join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, subquery

Is it possible to use subquery return as a table name in join?

**Dynamic Table(dynamictable)**

```
+--------+--------------+----------+-----------+--------+
| tableid| tablename    | settings | pack_type | status |
+--------+--------------+----------+-----------+--------+
|     24 | xxxxxx       | NULL     | F         | A      |
|     25 | YYYYYY       | NULL     | M         | A      |
|     30 | ZZZZZZ       | NULL     | M         | A      |
|     26 | AAAAAA       | NULL     | M         | A      |
+--------+--------------+----------+-----------+--------+
```

**Product Table(products)**

```
+--------------+------------+
| tableid      | product_id |
+--------------+------------+
|           30 |          1 |
|           30 |          2 |
|           25 |          3 |
|           30 |          4 |
+--------------+------------+
```

**xxxxxx**

```
+------------+--------------+
| product_id | product_cost |
+------------+--------------+
|          1 |          350 |
|          2 |          200 |
|          4 |          200 |
+------------+--------------+
```

i.e(for example):

```
select * 
  from products as p 
  left join (select tablename 
               from dynamictable as d 
              where d.tableid = p.tableid) as dt 
    on dt.product_id = p.product_id;
```

Comment: Yes....have you tried it..? but you forget to include `dt.product_id` in return

Comment: Mysql is not sql server

Comment: build dynamic sql statements.

Comment: @dipesh: Yes i tried .. it throws mysql error unknown column 'p.tableid' and if i put any directly value means instead of 'p.tableid' & the error shows unknown column 'dt.product_id'.

Comment: in the subquery p.tableid will through error as because there is no alias for p inside subquery

Answer (score 1):

You need to use LEFT JOIN into subquery.

```
select * 
  from products as p 
  left join (select tablename,products.tableid 
               from dynamictable as d
               left join products on d.tableid = products.tableid
            ) as dt 
    on dt.product_id = p.product_id;
```